# MySQL STR_TO_DATE hour formatting

Tags: mysql, time, datetime-format, str-to-date

I'm trying to format a string containing a time-value with the STR_TO_DATE function. The time value is : hour(0-23) without leading zero + minute (00-59)
e.g. 800, 1245 or 1535. To format these values I tried to use the %k hour specifier as described in the MySQL5.5 documentation, but this does not work if the hour is without a leading zero:

Does not work:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| SELECT STR_TO_DATE("800","%k%i"); |
+-----------------------------------+
| NULL                              |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Works as expected:

```
+------------------------------------+
| SELECT STR_TO_DATE("1855","%k%i"); |
+------------------------------------+
| 18:55:00                           |
+------------------------------------+

+-----------------------------------+
| SELECT STR_TO_DATE("0800","%k%i");|
+-----------------------------------+
| 08:00:00                          |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: For me, all three give NULLs.

Comment: I'm working on MySQL 5.5 and double checked the statements (on console and in web-gui) and they give the above (wrong) output

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LPAD()` to add a leading zero:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(LPAD("800", 4, 0), "%k%i");
```